# Calculating the sum of rows in a column when other columns satisfy a criterion

Tags: pandas, median

I've got a dataframe that looks like this  (code is at the bottom, if you care):

```
                A    B   C   D       E
Year Category                          
1980 Alpha     100  800  10  15  1.2350
     Bravo     200  700  20  25  2.3550
     Charlie   300  600  30  35  3.3600
     Delta     400  500  40  45  4.4448
1981 Alpha     500  400  50  55  5.5000
     Bravo     600  300  60  65  6.0000
     Charlie   700  200  70  75  7.2000
     Delta     800  100  80  85  8.0000
```

For each year, I'm trying to get the sum (and average) of columns A-D for all the rows where the value in E is larger than the median for that year.

So, for 1980 only Charlie & Delta qualify as having a value in column E that is greater than the median for that year.  Hence the result for column A should be
...sum = 300 + 400 = 700
... average = mean(300, 400) = 350

The closest  I can get here is using groupby / median

```
df.groupby(['Year']).median()
```

...but then I'm not quite sure what to do with the outputs. This gives me the medians for each year but I can't then easily link back these results to my initial dataframe.

Dataframe code:

```
data = {'A': [100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800], 
        'B': [800,700,600,500,400,300,200,100], 
        'C': [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80], 
        'D': [15,25,35,45,55,65,75,85], 
        'E': [1.235,2.355,3.36,4.4448,5.5,6,7.2,8]}

idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[1980, 1981],['Alpha','Bravo', 'Charlie','Delta']], names=['Year','Category'])
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=idx, columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'])
```

Comment: can you post the expected output too? That way it will be easier to validate

Comment: Of course.  For 1980, the respective sums for A-D are 700, 1100, 70, 80.  For 1981, the respective sums for A-D are 1500, 300, 150, 160.

Comment: And for the averages...in 1980 the expected outputs for A-D are 350, 550, 35, 40. For 1981, the corresponding values are 750, 150, 75, 80. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you can do a `groupby` on the first level and transform `median` on column E , then compare and drop off rows where E exceeds the median and sum on level=0:

```
s = df['E'].gt(df.groupby(level=0)['E'].transform('median'))
df.drop('E',1)[s].sum(level=0)
```

---

```
        A     B    C    D
Year                      
1980   700  1100   70   80
1981  1500   300  150  160
```

For having mean and sum stacked side by side you can do the same with concat and [`add_suffix`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_suffix.html) to identify:

```
s = df['E'].gt(df.groupby(level=0)['E'].transform('median'))
m = df.drop('E',1)[s]
pd.concat((m.sum(level=0).add_suffix('_sum'),m.mean(level=0).add_suffix('_avg')),axis=1)
```

---

```
      A_sum  B_sum  C_sum  D_sum  A_avg  B_avg  C_avg  D_avg
Year                                                        
1980    700   1100     70     80    350    550     35     40
1981   1500    300    150    160    750    150     75     80
```

Comment: Crikey. That looks amazing. Let me have a play around. Meantime - thank you very much.

Comment: @harrison10001 if it works , please consider upvoting/accepting the answer , TIA :)

Comment: ...(1) I don't want to lose column E...I want to include the sum ( or average) of the rows in col E which are bigger than the median. I've tried nixing the .drop('E',1) and running with df.[s].sum(level=0)...but that generates a syntax error. What should I change this to, please?

Comment: ...(2) In your code what is 's'? I understand that it's derived from column E when - after grouping on Years (ie level 0) - you're selecting the rows that are bigger than the median.  This isn't a dataframe...is it a series? Sorry for the basic question!

Comment: @harrison10001 1) : just get rid of the drop and use `df[s].sum(level=0)` , you had an extra `.` hence syntax error , 2: `s` is a series of booleans which returns True for rows ehere E is greater than median , so that we can do a [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)

Comment: anky_91 - you're a legend!! Thank you very much

Comment: @harrison10001 I am not but glad I could help :)